# GraniteDS Hello sample project using Mysql instead of HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, graniteds

I am new to JPA. Do anyone have any idea what else needs to be change in the sample to get it working with Mysql?

I was thinking the only changes that need to be done is the (jpa-config.xml)

I changed the data source to work with mysql.. I tested it out and its working. I create a table called Welcome on Mysql and have the columns name and message on it.

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdata</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>sa</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>sa</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am geting an error "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarEXception: could not execute query" whenever I try to insert an entry through the sample.

Comment: Change driver info to MySQL!! it seems your using org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Comment: "I changed the data source to work with mysql" ... post above.. I know the mysql setup is working because for the login system, I tied it with that datasource

Comment: Which Hibernate grammar have you configured?

Comment: I assume this is the grammar "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect". I will try the mysql grammar